# Pycharm run button faded out/notworking

Tags: python, pycharm

Im a new python developer and my pycharm run button is faded out it is unclickable how can imake it come bach (version-2019.2)

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens while Pycharm is indexing.
Check if it's the case by looking at the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall pycharm and make sure your python path is correct saved in your computer system.